# What's the best way to debug variables in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I need to debug some `variables` (requests) in my `Controller`. I've read that you can output `variables` into a `view` with functions like `dd()`. My frontend is built with `Vuejs` and it seems to be a hassle to echo them out from the `Controller` to the frontend. Are there better ways than echoing them out? Is it possible to log them?

**`NewsletterController.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class NewsletterController extends Controller
{
    public function submit(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required | email'
        ]);

        $data = array('email' => $request);

        dd($data);

        DB::table('newsletter')->insert($data);

        return response()->json(null, 200);
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to debug `$data` variable in this case?

Comment: Take a look at Ray from spatie. https://spatie.be/docs/ray/v1/introduction . Really helpful when debugging vue apps using Laravel. I also use the debug bar for laravel  barryvdh/laravel-debugbar . you can open all requests in the bar.

Comment: In this context I think [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) might be your best bet. It will be a real pain to set up properly and you may need to run `php artisan serve` instead of your normal setup for a bit, but (assuming you have an IDE that can debug) it's probably worth the effort long term

Comment: @apokryfos xdebug is indeed another option. But doesn't it slow down the application a lot (thats what i've noticed).

Comment: Another suggestion in conjunction with the above is to simply [`Log`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging) output to a file.

Comment: @GertB. yes it does, but usually in development environments performance is not as much of a concern as capability to debug (and if you set it up you can enable it and disable it only when needed)

Comment: So there are 2 options for me, 1. is `xdebug` which should be possible in phpstorm and I'm using `php artisan serve` anyway with `npm watch` and 2. `log` a seperate file. Think I'm going to try 2. first because it sounds like less work. Now just to find out how to create files in Laravel :-)

Comment: @apokryfos It's not a big concern indeed, but was something that i did not like about xdebug, and why i switched to Ray. I was wondering if it was more of a configuration mistake I could fix

Answer (score 3):

I came accross this:

```
\Log::info(print_r($var, true));
```

which dumps a variable or any content into `laravel.log` in a somehow human readable format.

Answer (score -1):

dd is fine. You can inspect the output in the console.

Or you can dump the variable as json with

```
echo json_encode($data);
die;
```

Comment: How do I inspect output from `echo` in the console? It doesn't show anything for me

Comment: Using echo json_encode makes no sense.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov indeed, you could view it in the network tab in the browsers debug, but still, not a good way of debugging

Answer (score -1):

You can use `var_dump`

```
var_dump($data);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: In Laravel we use `dump()` or `dd()`, not var_dump